# Create a new table in Power Bi using previously imported tables joining two tables

Tags: sql, database, powerbi, integration, reporting

How can I create an intermediary table using Query editor by joining two tables in Power BI.

There are two tables Person and Email which have a common Key of PersonID.

Person
PerrsonID
Name
LastName

Email
PeronID
EmailID
Email

Please let me know if you require any additional information.

Comment: You are upto merging two queries?

Comment: In power query editor, use the second option "Merge Queries as New" to join your 2 tables and get a new table.

Answer (score 1):

First, start `Power Query Editor` by clicking `Transform data` button in the ribbon:

[image]

It will open a new window, where you will see the list of your tables (called `Queries`). Click `Combine` button:

[image]

There are two options - `Append Queries` and `Merge Queries`. Each of them has two options (the dropdown next to the menu item) - as new or not. If you choose `as new`, the result will be a separate new table. Otherwise the first table will be transformed by this operation.

`Append Queries` will combine the tables in such a way, that the result will have all the columns from both tables, but the rows will be appended in the result (like `union all` in SQL). In your case, you should use `Merge Queries` - it will combine rows from both tables into a single row (like `join` in SQL). So make sure `Person` and `Email` tables are selected in the combo boxes and click on `PersonID` column in both to define the key:

[image]

`Join Kind` should be `Inner`, or if you want to also show persons without e-mail addresses `Left Outer` (assuming `Person` is the top table). It will create a new column `Email` of type `Table`. Click on the button in the column's title to expand it:

[image]

Select which columns to be included in the result (`PersonID` is not needed, because it will be a duplicate, `EmailID` probably also can be excluded):

[image]

The result will be what you ask for. The new columns will have a prefix or suffix, but you can double-click the column title and rename it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, My dataset contains about 10 million rows in both the tables and Merge is consuming large amounts of time. Do you think if there is any better way we could do this?

Comment: Join them at the data source.